# Is it possible to log the IP address in php error_log?

Tags: php, logging, ip-address, error-log

I have been working with PHP for years and have never really thought about this until now. Obviously there are custom formats for display apache logs, but is there anything that can be done with php's error_log by php.ini?

I'd like to log the IP address of the originating error without having to modify every function on my website and include `error_log($_REQUEST['REMOTE_ADDR'].' error etc');`

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: You can manually insert the IP as you do with the `error_log()` function, but there's no option in PHP to make internally generated errors get logged with the IP. Not all scripts run under a webserver, so IP addresses wouldn't be available.

Comment: How about a custom error handler that does the logging?

Comment: Pekka is right, using your custom error handler you can do whatever you want: log REMOTE_ADDR, HTTP_USER_AGENT, REQUEST_URI, HTTP_REFERER, HTTP_X_FORWARDER_FOR etc, send those errors to your email, redirect users and other.

Answer (score 0):

Apache should log this for you.

Here is an example from the error log for one of my php sites:

```
[Thu Mar 03 06:32:29 2011] [error] [client 188.226.15.54] PHP Notice: Undefined variable: profileRow in /public/html/mysite/profile.php on line 22
```

In my httpd.conf file, I have the following defined for the site

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com.error.log
```

Assuming you have the correct error level set for php, you should see your errors here.

Comment: I turned on the log in apache, but it simply logs apache errors, not php errors. I'm looking at the php error log file and there are plenty of errors showing up in there that are not showing up in the apache ErrorLog